# Do I have to use a DNS PTR?

Tags: networking

I am currently working on a site in my free time with a few other guys and we are wanting to redirect xxx.com to our new site, yyy.com.

So we have xxx.com set to redirect the 216.111.11.1 which is the IP for yyy.com. However, this just says the website is unavailable so it seems as though we need a DNS PTR to redirect 216.111.11.1 to yyy.com.

Is there any way to do this without a DNS PTR? The pointer will cost us $15 and it just seems like there should be some better way to go about doing this.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're confused.  A PTR record is a reverse DNS entry which resolves an IP address back to a hostname.  This is generally used to identify what role an IP address plays or to confirm that an e-mail server is who it says it is.

If you want to direct one domain to another via HTTP, you have a couple of options:

1. Point the old domain back to the old hosting provider and have them put a Location response header with a 301 status code to point to the new domain name.
2. Do #1 with your new provider.
3. Configure your web hosting at the new provider to recognize the old domain name as a virtual host for the new domain and have them run concurrently.

Either way, it will have little to do with DNS specifically and more to do with the web server configuration wherever the DNS is directing the old domain name.

Answer (score 2):

You can't redirect DNS PTR records.  The PTR record should point back at an A record.  You would need this if you had an email server on the IP address.  Web Services do not require a PTR record.

xxx.com can be setup as a CNAME for yyy.com.  This will result in xxx.com being directed to the IP address(es) of yyy.com.  www.xxx.com will go nowhere.

It seems yyy.com does not have a web server or is using virtual hosting and recognizes that xxx.com is not yyy.com.  It is common to configure web servers on www.yyy.com rather than yyy.com.

Comment: Would I setup xxx.com as a CNAME for yyy.com with the hosting company for xxx.com or yyy.com?

I assume xxx.com but I'm not sure.

Comment: The CNAME for xxx.com is a DNS enntry for xxx.com.  You may also want a CNAME for www.xxx.com. They can both point to the same entry.  yyy.com is then hosting the Internet presence for xxx.com.